# Writing USB driver for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, driver, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write a USB device driver for Raspberry Pi board (practising on my Ubuntu desktop first).
Whenever two flash drives are inserted, data from second will automatically be copied into the first flash drive.
Whenever a flash drive and a printer are connected, the contents of files in a specific PRINT folder in the flash drive will be automatically printed.

1) Is this entirely feasible ?

I have written a small driver which is able to register my Transcend pen drive.
While reading through Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition (3rd chapter), I understood that file operations that are required for USB data transfer should be requested from the user space only and that they cannot be done from kernel space (ie. from inside my module/driver)

2) Is my understanding correct ? (If it is, then this project becomes  impossible..)

Comment: Why would you do this as a driver? Instead you could make a user-space program that uses e.g. [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) or similar to receive events when a USB unit is connected, and then check type of the unit and then perform appropriate actions.

Comment: I would go so far as to say this could be solved using udev and a few scripts.